# How to get event on a new page

Tags: javascript, events

Here is the thing:

I will open a new page named NewWindow to draw some mark up on a canvas, such as an arrow, line or circle.

The Key problem is that I use

```
event.pageX;
event.pageY;
```

to get the coordinate. But I don't know how to get the event object for the new window.
Sometime I will get the event undefined error if I use

```
event=NewWindow.event.
```

Is there any one know how to do it???

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the windows `onload` method to get the event property.

`window.onload = function (event) { }`